# html, multiple event handlers, order of operation: onblur="fcnOne(); fcnTwo();"

Tags: html, onblur

googled for a bit, but I don't see an answer about the following.  say i have an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" id="pi" value="3.14159" 
   onblur="fcnOne(); fcnTwo();" >
```

Is there a defined order for how fcnOne() and fcnTwo() are invoked?

Comment: can you show a sample on jsfiddle how it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The string used inside the event-handler is javascript so it will follow js conventions. Any thing you would put inside it will behave like js so if you use there something like:

```
 onblur="this.value = 1; console.log('2')"
```

First the value would change then it would be printed. So same with calling functions, `fcnOne` first `fcnTwo` next according to the order.

Comment: hmmm - i'm seeing behavior where fcnTwo() seems to be being executed first.  double checking...  (this is chrome, up to date)

Comment: Just tried it on chrome and works the same, can you share your functions?